# Jmter complicated regular expression solution?

Tags: regex, jmeter

I need to extract the id which is D1600-2016-03-10-1457626261655 by providing the right boundry  "asOf":"2016-03- ... how can I extract value from it .also
"batch":{"id":"D1600"}

value is not static it is changed for each row.

```
{"id":"D1600-2016-03-10-1457626261655","batch":{"id":"D1600"},"asOf":"2016-03-10T16:11:57Z"..}
```

Comment: Starting from JMeter 3.0 you have a [JSON Path PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor). Use regex only on plain text. For marked up texts, dedicated tools should be used.

Comment: could you give me some code for it because i am new in performance testing

Comment: Something like `$.asOf`, see [JSONPath expressions syntax](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/). Or `$..asOf[0]`. It depends on the JSON  response structure.